# Extract second, third and fourth word of a cell in a googlesheet

Tags: excel, google-sheets

Good morning, mates!

I have a google spreadsheet  generatin activities informations, like the following below, where the phrase is inserted in one cell per row:

```
April 19, 2018 at 12:07AM
April 19, 2018 at 12:07AM
April 19, 2018 at 12:15AM
April 19, 2018 at 12:15AM
April 19, 2018 at 11:43AM
April 19, 2018 at 11:43AM
```

And this rows are constantly updating with new activities informations, reporting activities related to time, month, year and day.

I would like to split that information into 4 cells, instead of just one.

> [Month][Day][Year][Time] <---- each one in a separated cell.

To do that, i think that i would need a formula  to extract the month of the phrase to one new cell, then would need to take the Day for another cell, then the year and then the time. But i have no clue on how to do that. Could you guys help me?

Thanks a lot!

Comment: They are actual date in cell or just stored as string?

Comment: Just a string :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If a string as shown:

The basic formula to extract as a date, which I will put in A2 so I can reference A2 going forwards rather than a long formula, assuming A1 has string is

```
=SUBSTITUTE(TRIM(SUBSTITUTE(Left(A1,find("at",A1)-1),CHAR(32)," ")),",","")
```

gives:

```
April 19 2018
```

I can then extract other parts with

**Month**

```
=choose(month(A2),"January","February","March","April","May","June","July","August","September","October","November","December")
```

**Day**

```
=day(A2)
```

**Year**

```
=year(A2)
```

**Time**

```
=right(TRIM(SUBSTITUTE(A1,CHAR(32)," ")),len(TRIM(SUBSTITUTE(A1,CHAR(32)," ")))-(find(":",TRIM(SUBSTITUTE(A1,CHAR(32)," ")),1)-3))
```

**In sheet:**

[image: In sheet formulas]

You can of course embed the formulas and avoid using A2. I just found it easier to read. An example embedding for day would be:

```
=day(SUBSTITUTE(TRIM(SUBSTITUTE(Left(A1,find("at",A1)-1),CHAR(32)," ")),",",""))
```

You could of course also work with DATEVALUE provided you convert start string to something recognised as a date. Example with day again:

```
  =DAY(DATEVALUE(SUBSTITUTE(TRIM(SUBSTITUTE(Left(A1,find("at",A1)-1),CHAR(32)," ")),",","")))
```

Answer (score 1):

[google-spreadsheet](/questions/tagged/google-spreadsheet)

`=SPLIT(REGEXREPLACE(A14,"(.*),(.*)at (.*)","$1$2$3")," ")`

Comment: I am sorry, but didn't work, as image shows: https://drive.google.com/file/d/1U_VmcDC4XHJYhhfbKi2JvJI4y2lFJP6k/view?usp=sharing

Comment: @Paulo Replace the ,  to ;

Answer (score 0):

You can convert to a true datetime with,

```
=--SUBSTITUTE($A1, " at ", " ")
```

1. Show `April` in the cell with a cell number format of `mmmm`.
2. Show `4` in the cell with a cell number format of `m`.
3. Put `4` in the cell with `=MONTH(--SUBSTITUTE($A1, " at ", " "))`.
4. Put the string *April* in the cell with `=TEXT(--SUBSTITUTE($A1, " at ", " "), "mmmm")`.

I'm sure you can figure out day, year and string time. For a true time value use either,

```
=MOD(--SUBSTITUTE($A1, " at ", " "), 1)
=TIMEVALUE(--SUBSTITUTE($A1, " at ", " "))
```

[image]

Comment: Assuming they are US date format? I tried Text(,"mmmm") and got January not April. So for me, it read as 4/1 not 1/4  hence my ugly Choose.......: :-( I know you must have a clever way to handle this!!

Comment: `=--SUBSTITUTE($A1, " at ", " ")` should put it into a raw datetime like `43209.00486`. If it can do that, everything else is rudimentary. If it doesn't, I have to question why an EN-US datetime is being used on a non-EN-US system and why that wasn't mentioned in the question.

Comment: Hi, the comment above wasn't from me (owner of the question). Still, i tried to use your solution, but didn't worked, as the image shows:https://drive.google.com/file/d/1orGMCSyHctKpKdvQB1w6fdjxMvRIWknz/view?usp=sharing

Comment: Sorry to not to mention, my language is Portuguese. The string is in english because the system automatically generate the strings in english. Sorry again to not mention.

Comment: But i am not having any results with the formula that you gave me. :(

Answer (score 0):

[google-spreadsheet](/questions/tagged/google-spreadsheet)

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(REGEXEXTRACT(A2:A7,"^(\w+)\s+(\d+),\s+(\d{4})\s+at\s+(.+)$"))
```

- \w word
- \d digit
- \s space

Comment: sorry, doenst work. Am i doing something wrong? Image shows how i tried to use your suggestion: https://drive.google.com/file/d/1SGa7P67np-gQTnAhMfz4zKaO5M3gGNFe/view?usp=sharing